# How to avoid TS2590: Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent

Tags: typescript

I've dumbed down the api errors from my application to [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&fbclid=IwAR25vnMMFjnVQKTZYusd9P9dQmySEGcUIHl7jotErBHAaEbJCWDIrYhae-4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nAJANQIYA2ArigM5wC+cAZlBCHAOREzAHBIC0SqpjA3AChBAYwgA7UvACyAUQDK8gIIBxBXAC8GQXDghSAcwCMALib7jjADQ69hgExnGF+9dsWAzE89vdFgCzehv6+dgYArEERblR45GKSMEKiElJwslBQACrIKEaa2roZUAD6RmVm6La6YgAmKGZGNroUzemZZSWOhbpwdQ1w9m2ttsWdXj01EPVmHsNtY+WBk33TA-7zox3lkSv9ZuGbRdslAGyV1aszcKdH7aXlAOwXvVcDj3eLJQAcL737cG+nxOAE4-lNriDgQ8ygAGcFvRqwzaxeKpJLCBJpYo5VD2ApVY6lewVPZrRoouBxVaJZJY+A43IeAlbUoeUmE-7kuBNWwjVE0qR09H3XEofwsoklfwcy4A3ktGwC+nCxKi3LhSX3ErhWWveWU6kq4Q8NBKMDAYrQchaTkAbTkilUCgAdBYjABdMy4QgkUgAHlNEGo6tQRgAfEJdA6FMo1PI3Q4vdh8MQyIHcsHQ3lw3AAD4p33poMhxl4yO2GNO+OJgweZM+tMBkvZiP5wtNjOoLNllAeCvRx1x10BBupv1dlA9zJitsFxsTlu9-wDuBV4cJizhMdF5uZ0sz3JzjuL-fZ8IVijJU1wABKZEgkhQ-ukZFIeAMaBQAA8YChxLU5ALsWZ5Ds68jhrmtq2CgmTQGY5qWnBUCkA6b4figHpCFewgAPS4XAZDsOIMCcLUwDvgARgQKCcOIP6kcRaAAAKmqQIhQMAYCkURwAkbh4gQJwRDiEQpAoLUnAAG54ChgjUCJIisBICBkDAL7oZ+hG-v+gEniB3YhmB8aQQAFAAlGY96kI+4kaaQ76frmnJQCgMBEFA4grLBdBQGYvZGC6XwKpQ2GCEAA). It throws `Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.`.

1. How do I avoid it? (smaller api is not an option)
2. How do I make TS ignore it / increase the cap?
3. (optionally) Why does it happen? I've noticed in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33130) they mention that the cap of union types is 100000, and the playground code has 5 error types, 10 errors in first type, but I'm really not sure about the details.

Some things that didn't help:

1. `$Values` vs `ValuesType`
2. different typescript 4.x version (I can't go to 3.4)
3. type aliases
4. unique error codes
5. (**Edit**) `$Values<typeof ErrType1 & typeof ErrType2>` instead of `$Values<typeof ErrType1> | $Values<typeof ErrType2>`

**Edit:** as per request, directly posted code:

```
import type { $Values } from 'utility-types';

const MESSAGES = {
  msg1: 'msg1',
  msg2: 'msg2',
  msg3: 'msg3',
  msg4: 'msg4',
  msg5: 'msg5',
} as const;

const ErrType1 = {
  Err_1_1: {
    code: 1,
  },
  Err_1_2: {
    code: 2,
  },
  Err_1_3: {
    code: 3,
  },
  Err_1_4: {
    code: 4,
  },
  Err_1_5: {
    code: 5,
  },
  Err_1_6: {
    code: 6,
  },
  Err_1_7: {
    code: 7,
  },
  Err_1_8: {
    code: 8,
  },
  Err_1_9: {
    code: 9,
  },
  Err_1_10: {
    code: 10,
  },
} as const;

const ErrType2 = {
  Err_2_1: {
    code: 1,
  },
} as const;

const ErrType3 = {
  Err_3_1: {
    code: 1,
  },
} as const;

const ErrType4 = {
  Err_4_1: {
    code: 1,
  },
} as const;

const ErrType5 = {
  Err_5_1: {
    code: 1,
  },
} as const;

type ApiErrors = {
  [MESSAGES.msg1]: $Values<typeof ErrType1>;
  [MESSAGES.msg2]: $Values<typeof ErrType1> | $Values<typeof ErrType2>;
  [MESSAGES.msg3]: $Values<typeof ErrType1> | $Values<typeof ErrType3>;
  [MESSAGES.msg4]: $Values<typeof ErrType1> | $Values<typeof ErrType4>;
  [MESSAGES.msg5]: $Values<typeof ErrType1> | $Values<typeof ErrType5>;
};

type Response<Message extends $Values<typeof MESSAGES>> = {
  error: ApiErrors[Message];
};

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
function test<Message extends $Values<typeof MESSAGES>>(): Response<Message> {
  return {
    error: ErrType1.Err_1_1,
  };
}
```

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: I'm not sure specifically where it's happening. You don't have to change your API, but you could change the way you represent the types. There are a lot of specific types that look very similar. Also, I'm not sure why you are creating variables to represent types.

Comment: I can't find a way to represent the types that would work, that's what would help me the most.

They look very similar because I renamed everything to be as simple as possible for the example, in reality it spans 4 files and is a mess.

I'm making variables, because I want to use it as variables, see at the bottom:
return { error: ErrType1.Err_1_1 };